# Django: Getting a DoesNotExist exemption on the terminal but data is selected

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm working on project 4 for CS50W (network). I have a weird issue I just noticed:

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("create_post", views.create_post, name="create_post"),
    path("<str:username>", views.profile, name="profile")
]
```

view giving problem:

```
def profile(request, username):

    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(owner=user).order_by('-timestamp')

    print(f'Current username: {user.username} ({user.email})')

    return render(request, 'network/profile.html', {
        'username': user,
        'followed': user.followers.filter(username=request.user.username),
        'posts': posts
    })
```

Terminal log:

```
**Current username: FernandoBorea (fernando@email.com)**
[26/Jul/2023 00:40:25] "GET /FernandoBorea HTTP/1.1" 200 2651
Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fernandoborea/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/fernandoborea/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/fernandoborea/studies/CS50W/TestingCICD/project4/cs50w-project4/network/views.py", line 104, in profile
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
  File "/home/fernandoborea/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fernandoborea/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 637, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
network.models.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
[26/Jul/2023 00:40:26] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 71927
```

As you can see, the user variable does get a User instance back as it is printed to the terminal and everything on the site works perfectly, but I have no idea why I'm getting the error reported on the terminal. Another strange thing is upon loading the default route (index) it also shows the error, even though the view giving problems is not called.

Any help is highly appreciated!

**Update with more logs**

For some reason, even when visiting the index route ('/') it still shows that error coming from a view that hasn't been requested.

Additional logs, this time it shows loading the index page to then navigate to the user's page:

```
[26/Jul/2023 01:52:40] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3667
Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fernandoborea/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/fernandoborea/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/fernandoborea/studies/CS50W/TestingCICD/project4/cs50w-project4/network/views.py", line 104, in profile
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
  File "/home/fernandoborea/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fernandoborea/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 637, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
network.models.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
[26/Jul/2023 01:52:42] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 71940
Current username: FernandoBorea (fernando@email.com) (True)
[26/Jul/2023 01:52:44] "GET /FernandoBorea HTTP/1.1" 200 2651
Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fernandoborea/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/fernandoborea/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/fernandoborea/studies/CS50W/TestingCICD/project4/cs50w-project4/network/views.py", line 104, in profile
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
  File "/home/fernandoborea/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fernandoborea/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 637, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
network.models.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
[26/Jul/2023 01:52:44] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 71953
```

**Update 2, models**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    following = models.ManyToManyField(to='User', related_name='followers_relname', symmetrical=False, blank=True)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(to='User', related_name='following_relname', symmetrical=False, blank=True)


class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='owner')
    post = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(to=User, related_name='liked_posts', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.owner}: {self.post}'
```

Comment: I note the print() in your view doesn't have asterisks. Are you sure the one in your error traceback is coming from the view? it seems to occur before the actual GET for the page.  The other thing to check is to make sure the user is question is a based on your (presumably custom) user model in /network, and not a django default user created earlier.

Comment: Yes, it's comming from the print, I wanted to make it bold when posting it here and just noticed it doesn't work on code chunks  regarding the user, yeah, it's a custom User model based on AbstractUser, so it does have the username field

Comment: Add your `models.py` file for better understanding of the problem

Comment: Done, models added to the question

Comment: Hint for debugging: move up the `print` statement to see the contents of `request, username` to the very top of your `profile()` view or better yet set a breakpoint there. You don't actually know from this code what gets passed as `username=username`, maybe there is a loose slash in there or something like that.

Comment: `Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico`   has occurred multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's notable about the traceback is the error is actually coming **after** the image call.

Your path for the profile view, `path("<str:username>", views.profile, name="profile")` essentially matches ANY string.

You know what's also a string?  `/favicon.ico`.  Your urls path is actually matching the request for the image!

You need to make the path a bit more discriminating. I think the error should disappear if you replace your current path with

`path("<str:username>/profile", views.profile, name="profile")`

and changed any links that needed changing to that.